# Flexible hose to connect to 2" PVC

Tags: plumbing, woodworking, central-vacuum

I'm setting up a dust collection system in my woodshop. It has lines that I mounted to the wall of 2" outer diameter PVC. I'm trying to connect one end of it to a flexible hose to use as a hand vacuum.

Common vacuum hose sizes close to this range seem to be [1 7/8"](https://smile.amazon.com/WORKSHOP-Wet-Dry-Accessories-WS17823A/dp/B00FX34QEU/ref=sr_1_2?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1467308700&sr=1-2&keywords=1%207%2F8%20inch%20vacuum%20hose) and [2 1/2"](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B019C23JIQ/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER).

I've found some [rubber couplings](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Plumbing-Pipes-Fittings-Specialty-Pipe-Fittings/2%22/N-5yc1vZbuu1Z1z0u2la) that can connect to the 2" PVC, but the only options for sizes on the other end seem to be 1 1/2", 2", 3", etc.

Where can I find a proper 2" to 1 7/8" rubber coupling? Or a 2" to 1 1/2" coupling? Or is my best bet to just try to use the 2" to 2" coupling and connect it to the 1 7/8" hose?

Comment: I am not sure about the coupling but use caution when picking up sawdust with your system. If you feel the hair on your arms or head starting to stand up don't get close to anything metal. My dad built a 3" system after several of us getting hurt (1 hospital trip). he pulled out the plastic and put metal pipe in. I know I saw an arc jump over a foot when a employee backed up two close to a saw  and he was out like a lite, He received several stitches from where he hit his head. Just be aware when you start picking stuff up it can create a hefty charge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several workshop specific brick-n-mortar stores out there that also sell online. Two that come to mind are Rockler and Woodcraft. Both sell what you are looking for. Both also have solutions for the static buildup that Ed was describing. I personally use flexible hose that has a wire built into it that is grounded. My system is a 3" PVC pipe around the garage. There are gates in several locations where I can attach the flexible hose. The gates are grounded. Get yourself a free catalog from both places. Rockler and Woodcraft are pretty pricey but they have items that you will not find anywhere else.